# Cannot find name 'createError'.ts(2304)

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, syntax

When I try this code:

```
import httperrors as createError from 'http-errors';
```

I get this error message:

> Cannot find name 'createError'.ts(2304)

But the following one works:

```
import httperrors  from 'http-errors';
const createError = httperrors;
```

What is the difference and how can I write it in one line?

Comment: When writing a default import, you need to use the `a as b` syntax to provide an alias. You can use `import createError from 'http-errors'`

Comment: @vamsiampolu: I think I got it! Thanks